# How to display value from the database in input tag in django?

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I am having an HTML template for displaying my form data to allow users to view as well as edit their data:-

```
<div id="div_id_first_name" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_first_name" class="requiredField"> First name<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
    <div class="">
        <input type="text" name="first_name" value="{{p_form.first_name}}" maxlength="20" class="textinput textInput form-control" required id="id_first_name" />
    </div>
</div>
<div id="div_id_last_name" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_last_name" class="requiredField"> Last name<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
    <div class=""><input type="text" name="last_name" value="{{p_form.last_name}}" maxlength="20" class="textinput textInput form-control" required id="id_last_name" /></div>
</div>
<div id="div_id_id_no" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_id_no" class="requiredField"> ID No.<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
    <div class=""><input type="text" name="id_no" value="{{p_form.}}" maxlength="20" class="textinput textInput form-control" required id="id_id_no" /></div>
</div>
<div id="div_id_phone_no" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_phone_no" class="requiredField"> Phone No.<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
    <div class=""><input type="text" name="phone_no" value="{{p_form.}}" maxlength="20" class="textinput textInput form-control" required id="id_phone_no" /></div>
</div>
<div id="div_id_cgpa" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_cgpa" class="requiredField"> CGPA<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
    <div class=""><input type="text" name="cgpa" value="{{p_form.}}" maxlength="20" class="textinput textInput form-control" required id="id_cgpa" /></div>
</div>
<div id="div_id_degree" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_degree" class="requiredField"> Degree<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
    <div class=""><input type="text" name="degree" value="{{p_form.}}" maxlength="20" class="textinput textInput form-control" required id="id_degree" /></div>
</div>
<div id="div_id_stream" class="form-group">
    <label for="id_stream" class="requiredField"> Stream<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label>
    <div class=""><input type="text" name="stream" value="{{p_form.}}" maxlength="20" class="textinput textInput form-control" required id="id_stream" /></div>
</div>
```

I am rendering this page with the view funstion:-

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST,
                                   request.FILES,
                                   instance=request.user.profile)
        if u_form.is_valid() and p_form.is_valid():
            u_form.save()
            p_form.save()
            messages.success(request, f'Your account has been updated!')
            return redirect('profile')

    else:
        u_form = UserUpdateForm(instance=request.user)
        p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(instance=request.user.profile)
        v_form = ProfileViewForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {
        'u_form': u_form,
        'p_form': p_form,
        'v_form': v_form
    }

    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', context)
```

I am trying to get this:-
[image]

But The view turns out to look something like this:-
[image]

I am unable to figure out how can I display those values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that p_form.first_name is an input field itself. Please try to add .value fields this way:

```
value="{{p_form.first_name.value}}"
```